# In Linux / Unix, is there a way to list every group ownership that appears under a specific folder path?

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, find, owner

As the title says...I need to go through a path and list every group that owns a file under that path...without knowing the names of the groups.

Example:

MyFolder contains:
-rw-rw-rw- 1 myuser group1  107717 Feb 26 08:03 thisfile
-rw-rw-rw- 1 myuser group2  114746 Mar  1 12:53 thatfile
-rw-rw-rw- 1 myuser group3  115327 Mar  2 08:42 theirfile
-rw-rw-rw- 1 myuser group4  110555 Mar 10 10:32 myfile
-rw-rw-rw- 1 myuser group5  102131 Feb  1 15:59 stupidfile

I would need this output:
group1
group2
group3
group4
group5

Bear in mind...This needs to be a command or script of some sort...my example is simple, but the actual folders are 5-10 subfolders deep, with hundreds of thousands of files, and potentially several dozen groups.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming GNU find:

```sh
find /path/to/MyFolder -printf "%g\n" | sort | uniq -c
```

will show all distinct groups owning files in the directory tree, and how many files each group owns.

Comment: wow...quick and easy...worked like a charm, thanks!!

Comment: If you want to get the groups for files only, not for directories, you can insert `-type f` before `-printf`